Override Variable or Event handler in Browser app through an Extension
My company uses a 3rd party service that is built with React.
There are some text field parts of the app that my company requires to be formatted a certain way. For various reasons we are not in a position to ask the vendor to update their software (we are one user of many).
I have been digging in to writing a browser extension (Firefox currently but I will need to turn it into a universal plugin for Chrome as well) to format and pre-fill some of the fields to assist the user experience.
Is it possible to have an extension access and update certain parts of the React components, or hook an event that renders a specific sub component and modify a parameter sent to that component?
One thing I have tried is to modify the html input fields themselves.  This works great but something is overwriting the new value when I focus out so I don't think this is the right approach.  I am guessing react is re-rendering and it is using the component state, which I haven't updated, to build the html, undoing my dom changes.
const selector = '#id'
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    const node = document.querySelector(selector)
    if (node) {
        observer.disconnect(); // Stop watching for changes to the node
        console.log(`Node found: ${document.querySelector(selector)}`);
        // do the work here
        node.value = fixValue(node.value)
    }
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
});

